# Validating Username and password using OWIN in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

Using Owin i want to validate the username and password but not to use the its default AspUser table but custom user table in MVC 5.

Answer (score -1):

If you use code first approach then check this [Model Validation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/models/validation.html)

In other words, if you don't want to use generated tables you have to write your own classes then migrate them to a database. In the process of writing classes you have add the validations too.

Comment: She asks how to use MVC password validator from code